# How to avoid Instagram login page everytime using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, pickle, webdriverwait

I am trying to make a selenium instagram script. My issue is I have to login my account every time.

If I use my normal google chrome, only one time login is enough. It's always stay logged in when ı open Chrome. But Chrome driver always aks for login.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import kullaniciBilgileri as kb
import os.path
from pathlib import Path
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import collections

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
link = "http://www.instagram.org"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="./chromedriver")
browser.get(url=link)
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=("username"))
password = browser.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=("password"))
username.send_keys(kb.userName)
password.send_keys(kb.password)
loginBtn = browser.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=("#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button > div"))
                               
loginBtn.click()
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While accessing your [**Instagram**](http://www.instagram.org**) to avoid loging in everytime, once you login for the first time using [pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73008126/7429447) module you can store the [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59878718/7429447) and reuse during your next login attempt as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pickle

driver.execute("get", {'url': 'http://www.instagram.org'})
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys("_SelmanFarukYılmaz_")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']").send_keys("Selman_Faruk_Yılmaz")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit'] div").click()
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
driver.quit()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.execute("get", {'url': 'http://www.instagram.org'})
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.execute("get", {'url': 'http://www.instagram.org'})
```